# Mapping a custom domain registered in Google Domains to a website in Google New-Sites

Tags: google-sites, google-domains

I had this working with old-Sites, but new-Sites messed everything up.
(1) Need to map orgchangedoctor.com & [www.orgchangedoctor.com](http://www.orgchangedoctor.com) to https://sites.google.com/site/orgchangedoctor
(2) Would like to map the entire URL including folders and html
(3) Lastly, have the orgchangedoctor.com url display on the browser (not the Sites address)

I have been going in circles with various help articles that make changes to Google Domains DNS (variations on Synthetic Records and Custom Resource Records), Google Domains Website (Build a website, Simple site, and use existing site), and Google new-Sites (Settings, Custom URL).

Comment: I think "custom URL" would be the way to go.  Have you tried these instructions yet? https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en  It says you just need a CNAME in DNS not synthetic records or custom resource records.

Comment: Stephen - I tried that before and just tried it again.  (1) I created the CNAME, (2) deleted the synthetic record that was there, and (3) assigned the custom URL in Sites.  Now, the page cannot be found.  Before I redid this action, I was getting to the website in Sites but it was requiring a login to edit and did not display my domain.

Comment: Stephen - Update after trying again later. - Now, my domain forwards to the website on new-Sites, but requires a login for editing.  The URL displayed is the Sites address - no mention of my domain, just trying to take me to edit mode on new-Sites.